# CSS Slider: trigger Animation with JavaScript (GreenSock)

Tags: javascript, css, slider, carousel, gsap

I have a Question about this code:

codepen.io/ettrics/pen/WvoRQo

I'm trying to animate the content inside the slider with greensock (tweenmax) using javascript. 
How can i achieve that?
Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: You're asking the community to understand and debug a ton of code here. Please, be more specific with you question.

Answer (score 1):

You just check [this](http://greensock.com/transitions/) and [also](http://greensock.com/forums/topic/11473-click-event-trigger-animation/)..

Sample animation with javascript here.

Html

```
<div id="overlay">
    <a id="close"> close </a>
    <h1>This is overlay content</h1>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries  
</div>
<div class="content">
    <a id="open"> open </a>
    <h2>This is page content</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries  
</div>
```

Css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  background-color: rgba(20,20,20,0.9);
}

#open {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #ea5;
}
#close {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #43e;
}
```

Jquery

```
//since there's a -100% translateY in the CSS, this just tells GSAP how things should be assigned between regular "y" and yPercent...
TweenLite.set(overlay, {y:0, yPercent:-100});

$('#open').on('click',
  function() {
    TweenMax.to(overlay, 0.8, {
      yPercent: 0
    });
  });

$('#close').on('click',
  function() {
    TweenMax.to(overlay, 0.8, {
      yPercent: -100
    });
  });
```